# Getting relationship count of certain objects (Core Data)

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, relationship

My core data model has a one to many relationship (pet owner to pets) and a table (using NSFetchedResultsController) showing all of the pet owners and needs to show how many of each animal they own (dogs, cats, etc). The problem is I can not just get the count of a specific pet (e.g. the count of how many dogs the owner has). I tried doing another query in each cell (inside cellForRowAt), but this is not efficient because cellForRowAt is called multiple times with each scroll.

The PetOwner model contains an id, name, age, etc, and a relationship to the Pet model where there can be many pets to one owner. The Pet model has id, name, type, age, etc, and a relationship to the PetOwner model where there can only be one owner for each pet

Since the owner can have multiple pets of different types and `petOwner.pets.count` only gives me a count of all of the pets they own (all types). I just want to get the count of a specific type of pet (e.g. dog).

**How can I get the count of just a specific animal linked to a specific pet owner?**

Comment: Please can you add more detail of your model and your FRC and TV code.

Comment: if I understood, why dont you just prepare the data you wanna show on `viewDidLoad` as an `Array` or `Dictionary` like `[(owner: Owner, countPets: Int64)]`

Comment: Added more detail @pbasdf